# shallow copy of linkedlist does not reflect changes when adding new node

Tags: java, linked-list

[image: diagram]
I have done a lot of readings but seems like I can't clear my confusion without asking here. Based on the diagram, when I create a a shallow copy of a linkedlist using clone(). A new linkedlist is created and the reference value of the head variable in the original is copied to the clone's and the rest of the nodes are shared. So if I add a new node using the clone, this should be visible to the orginal is it not? But when printing list1 out the value 3 is omitted. Can someone tell me why?

```
LinkedList<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
l1.add(1);
l1.add(2);
LinkedList<Integer> list2 = (LinkedList) l1.clone();
l2.add(3);
```

Comment: The given image in this question may correctly describe the definition of shallow copy, but does not describe how LinkedList.clone() is implemented. Nodes are indeed objects held by LinkedList, so it is reasonable that a shallow-copied LinkedList holds a reference to the same Nodes that the original holds. However, Node is just a helper class that should be kept in the black box. So LinkedList.clone() also copies the Nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clone()` creates new `LinkedList` structure and returns new reference to first node. Relation between these two `LinkedList`s is they share same node **`values`**. When you make some `add`\ `remove` operations on old or new list these operations will not change other list. This is why we do `copy` - we do not want to change original linked list structure when we change copy.

From `LinkedList.clone` documentation:

> Returns a shallow copy of this `LinkedList`. (The **elements themselves
>   are not cloned**.) 
>   `@return` a shallow copy of this `LinkedList` instance

Consider below example:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class LinkedListsApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LinkedList<AtomicInteger> l1 = new LinkedList<>();
        l1.add(new AtomicInteger(100));
        l1.add(new AtomicInteger(200));

        LinkedList<AtomicInteger> l2 = (LinkedList) l1.clone();
        l2.add(new AtomicInteger(300));

        System.out.println(l1);
        System.out.println(l2);

        // change element on first list
        l1.get(0).incrementAndGet();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("After change internal state of first element");
        System.out.println(l1);
        System.out.println(l2);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
[100, 200]
[100, 200, 300]

After change internal state of first element
[101, 200]
[101, 200, 300]
```

As we can see, when we change internal state of first element from first list it is visible for second list as well. So, there is no deep copy of each element value rather copy of structure - copy of nodes and order.

To make it absolutely clear, let's take a look on implementation in `Java 8`:

```
public Object clone() {
    LinkedList<E> clone = superClone();

    // Put clone into "virgin" state
    clone.first = clone.last = null;
    clone.size = 0;
    clone.modCount = 0;

    // Initialize clone with our elements
    for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
        clone.add(x.item);

    return clone;
}
```

Take a look on `for-each` loop. It iterates over original list and adds values to `clone` list. Method `add` creates new `Node` object which stores the same value as original list: `x.item`.

Comment: A linkedlist is just a class that has only 1 field which the ref variable of the head. Each node has data and a ref to its next node. Are you saying that the linkedlist is aware of all its child nodes? Like the linkedlist is a context of all the nodes?

Comment: @PeterNguyen, it contains 2 refs: `first` and `last`. It is "aware" but not directly only over these nodes. But clone is implemented in that way that new nodes are created and added to new list with content which is the same as in old list. If you have some doubts how clone works, you can check implementation which will answer on your doubts.

Comment: A linkedlist is just a class with one field which is a ref to a head node. Each node is an individual object which contains a ref to its next. Like you said, a shallow copy doesn't copy the node. So when i add a new node, the current last node's next variable refers to the next node. So this should be visible to both. Unless a linkedlist is a just container then what you are saying makes sense to me.

Comment: @PeterNguyen, I was not clear enough. It does not copy `value` which node "stores". But it create whole new node. So, if we have 10 instances of `User` class on `LinkedList` and we clone it we have 10 new `Node`'s which points to the same 10 instances of `User` class. We need to distinguish what is a node and what is a value stored by node. Sometimes when we say `node` we think `value` stored by node. In this case we need to be really precise to understand it correctly.

Comment: Ziober If that's the case, it's clear now. Thanks mate!

Comment: Ziober But one more thing, isn't a Node considered a class/object? clone() method doesn't create new object but rather a reference right? so how do we have 10 new nodes?

Comment: @PeterNguyen, yes we have because implementation call `clone.add(x.item)` method which create totally new node. New node has a reference to (stores) the same `value`. Take a look on my last edit, it should be clear now.

Comment: To clarify, clone() does create a new object.

Comment: @Sgene9, It is not an absolute requirement of [clone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) method. It depends from implementation which in every case should be checked if you want rely on it.

Comment: @MichałZiober The first word of the clone()'s javadoc is "Creates". If clone() doesn't return a newly created instance, it's an incorrect implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The clone() method creates an exact copy of the first linked list and then returns it to l2 here.  What is does is it creates a new instance and copies all the fields from the original one and then returns it to l2 object. If all we want is a shallow copy we can simply use an assignment operator, in that scenario any changes made to l1 will reflect on l2 as no new object is created but only a copy of the reference is created.

Comment: you are wrong. The assignment operator does not create a shallow copy. It simply copy the reference location of the linkedlist to a new variable. That means there's only 1 linkedlist but in the case of clone() method, there's 2. I know how to implement a linkedlist so i know a linkedlist is just a class that contains a reference of the root. It isn't directly aware of any other nodes besides the root.

Comment: thanks for correcting me... I was wrong in the assignment operator understanding....