# How to avoid the passing object after cloning in Java?

Tags: java

I have a Node object and want to make some clone objects from this orginal one. Below is my code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.setName("node1");
        node.setValue("1");
        node.setChildNodes(new ArrayList<>());

        Node node2 = cloneNode(node);
        Node childNode2 = new Node();
        childNode2.setName("childNode2");
        childNode2.setValue("1");
        List<Node> childNodes2 = node2.getChildNodes();
        childNodes2.add(childNode2);
        node2.setChildNodes(childNodes2);
        System.out.println(node.getChildNodes());

    }

    private static Node cloneNode(Node node) {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.setName(node.getName());
        newNode.setValue(node.getValue());
        newNode.setChildNodes(node.getChildNodes());
        return newNode;
    }

}

class Node {
    private String name;
    private String value;
    private List<Node> childNodes;

    //getter and setter
}
```

I created a first Node and create a second Node which is cloned from the first one. Then I would like to modify the childNodes list in the second Node object (node2) and then I realize that the childNodes list in the first Node(node) is also modified.

How can I avoid the list in the first Node being modified?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You clone the node, but you don't clone the children--it's the same list.

Comment: You need to do a deep copy and clone the child nodes as well

Comment: Show the code for `getChildNodes()` please.  It's likely you need to copy the list however.

Comment: Something like `newNode.setChildNodes(new ArrayList(node.getChildNodes()));` See also: [shallow copy of linkedlist does not reflect changes when adding new node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55080507/shallow-copy-of-linkedlist-does-not-reflect-changes-when-adding-new-node)

Comment: Yes, "and also clone its contents" which is a list of nodes.  You'll be copying forever.  This might be bad design/XY problem wrt your list of nodes or the idea that you should clone a node.

Comment: create a new Node, iterate over the old nodes' values and clone them as well into the new one

Comment: I'd ask if there's any chance that the node graph could be circular.  Can a node "lower down" refer to a node that's higher up?  Is this a tree or a more general graph?

Answer (score 2):

What you have done is a kind of `shallow clone`. You might want to clone deeper instead of

```
newNode.setChildNodes(node.getChildNodes())
```

You should clone the child nodes as well. Proper way is [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deep-shallow-lazy-copy-java-examples/)

Alternatively , you can just `serialize` and `deserialize` the object is the easy way of cloning deep objects

`Eg:` Just transform the `Node1` to `JSON` string and convert the string back to `Node2` (Tip: use the `gson` library)